# Failed to insert JTable data into database while the text field's data is inserted successfully

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try
    {
        String sql="insert into invoice (bill_no,name,number,title1,title2,title3,title4) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());


        //this is my code to insert data from jTable1 into database
        //but no entry is made in my database for the following lines
        int last=jTable1.getRowCount();
        String column1= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,0);
        String column2= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,1);
        String column3= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,2);
        String column4= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,3);

        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data saved");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
```

this is my code to insert the data into database 
there are no errors displaying but when i check my database then there is no entry for 
the `JTable` data into the database but the text field's data is inserted successfully
plz help me with this
give me a code to insert data from the `JTable` into database.
i'm a beginner, dont know much coding.

Comment: You were getting Exception. Try to print the stackTrace in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You have no error because you are not printing error in catch block.

You have to set data from `jTable` to `pst`.

```
try
{
    String sql="insert into invoice (bill_no,name,number,title1,title2,title3,title4) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
    pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
    pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());

    int last=jTable1.getRowCount();
    String column1= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,0);
    String column2= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,1);
    String column3= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,2);
    String column4= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,3);

    pst.setString(4,column1);
    pst.setString(5,column2);
    pst.setString(6,column3);
    pst.setString(7,column4);

    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data saved");

}
catch(Exception e)
{e.printStackTrace();}
```

You can see the exception by putting `e.printStackTrace()` in `catch block`.

Answer (score 0):

that was an incomplete code..
try this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            String sql="insert into invoice (bill_no,name,number,title1,title2,title3,title4) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
            pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
            pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());

            int last=jTable1.getRowCount();
            String column1= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,0);
            String column2= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,1);
            String column3= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,2);
            String column4= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,3);

            pst.setString(4,column1);
            pst.setString(5,column2);
            pst.setString(6,column3);
            pst.setString(7,column4);

            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data saved");

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```